# Constness error in SWIG-generated wrapper code for a Director

Tags: java, constants, swig

So, I'm trying to use [swig](http://www.swig.org) to wrap a c++ library to make JNI calls to it.  But, the _wrap.cxx file that swig is creating for me won't compile cleanly in g++.  What am I doing wrong?

Here's a simple test case that will reproduce the error, along with a couple of other cases that don't error.  My header file:

```
class MyClass {
};

class MyDirectored {
public:
  virtual void Overridable (MyClass const clz);
  virtual ~MyDirectored();
};
```

and here's my .i file:

```
%module("directors="1") swigtest
%{
#include "swig.h"
%}

%feature("director") MyDirectored

%include "swig.h"
```

I'm attempting to build via the following:

```
swig -c++ -package gen -java -outdir gen swig.i
g++ -c swig_wrap.cxx -o swig_wrap.o
```

And the g++ step yields the following error:

```
swig_wrap.cxx: In member function 'virtual void SwigDirector_MyDirectored::Overridable(MyClass)':
swig_wrap.cxx:436: error: invalid conversion from 'const MyClass*' to 'MyClass*'
```

Which appears to be a legitimate complaint - the resulting swig_wrap.cxx file looks like (lots of snippage)

```
void SwigDirector_MyDirectored::Overridable (MyClass const clz) {
  //...
  jlong jclz;
  //...
  *((MyClass **)&jclz) = &clz; //Error on this line
  //...
}
```

I get the same error in both swig 2.0.4 and 1.3.40, Linux and Windows.  Any suggestions?  Any g++ trick I could use to ignore the constness error?

Random notes: I can't control the input header, so changing the function signature is a no-go.  It doesn't appear to matter what type the input parameter is - class or struct.  Making it a const reference instead of a const value parameter does "fix" the error by causing SWIG to explicitly cast away the constness (but again, I can't change the input header).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Good question - I'm stumped on this one! Normally I'd suggest changing to a reference, but if you can't do this I'm not sure what the sensible workaround is.